# Implement a modal with checkbox with dotted line box around each two checkbox in jsf/html?

Tags: html, css, jsf, checkbox

I want to have a html/jsf code for below modal structue :

[image]

I only need to know how we can have dotted line boxes around two checkbox.

I need to implement above modal which I have shown.

What I did using jsf is :

```
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" class="input-element">
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="STAT 1 (Tyr701)" />
                    </label>&nbsp;
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" class="input-element">
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="STAT 1 (Tyr701)" />
                    </label>&nbsp;
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" class="input-element">
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="STAT 1 (Tyr701)" />
                    </label>&nbsp;
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" class="input-element">
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="STAT 1 (Tyr701)" />
                    </label>&nbsp;
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" class="input-element">
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="STAT 1 (Tyr701)" />
                    </label>&nbsp;
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="" class="input-element">
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                    <label> <h:outputText value="STAT 1 (Tyr701)" />
                    </label>
```

I just tried with above code which is just manually by adding check boxes and labels which is not good solution.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple example - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm6czm8f/):
HTML

```
<div class="input-box">
  <label class="label-float">
    <input type="checkbox" name="example" value="one">value one
  </label>

  <label class="label-float">
    <input type="checkbox" name="example" value="two">value two
  </label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.input-box {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
}
.input-box::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
.label-float {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width:50%;
}
```